# Django: proper way to filter using django-filters

Tags: django, django-filters

I am trying to filter contents against date time. I have following filter set.

`start_date = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name = "date_time", lookup_type = 'contains')`

I get following error for the url, `report/?start_date=2015-01-16`

`Incorrect datetime value: '%2015-01-16 00:00:00+05:45%' for column 'date_time' at row 1`

What is the correct way to set datetime filter?

Comment: I think this question is related to django-rest-framework. And I  guess contains filter is for string, not datetime

Answer (score 0):

As g33klord has pointed in the comments, your problem is the lookup type. Using `contains` doesn't make sense for a date time field as it translates into a SQL `LIKE` command.